# Is there any way to identify if type of an HTTP request is changed by the intercepter?

Tags: security, http, post, get

Is it possible to validate if an HTTP request originated from the client as GET, but was intercepted in between and converted to POST, or vice versa?

It is one of the security validations that is required as part of the project I am working on, but not getting enough clue about it. One of the way we thought of using as validation is to check if it is a GET request with a body than it could be POST. But that is just one case. Also if a POST is changed to GET by forging the request, I believe the data in the body can also be removed.

**edit:** Added more information about application and the intercepter

It is a regular Java web application developed using Struts with JSPs on the client side. The request from the web pages are being intercepted using Burp Suit Proxy to change the payload in the request.

Comment: Provide please more details, is it a web page which sends this requests or some app?

Comment: Intercepted by who? The go-to answer is to use TLS/SSL so your request is sent via the HTTPS protocol. This mitigates any MitM attacks.

Comment: @VitalyKulikov, I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: @SilverlightFox the requests are intercepted using Burp Suit Proxy. We have TLS implemented for our application. But when the requests are intercepted through proxy, most browsers are allowing users to bypass it by accepting the certificate error. Pardon me if it is silly question but couldn't it be a real life scenario?

Comment: This shouldn't be a security vulnerability unless the user is accessing content or bypassing controls by changing the request method. [See here for examples](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/http-verb-tempering-bypassing-web-authentication-and-authorization/). The mitigation is to do the access checks for all code paths, irrespective of the verb used.